# Is the Stargate now at Homeworld Command?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

The Stargate [wiki page for the SGU episode "Alliances"](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Alliances) says:

> Because Greer said that the Stargate is activating most likely the Stargate is now in Homeworld Command.

I watched the episode just a few moments ago and do not recall this; also, a search for "stargate", "gate" and "wormhole" in [the transcript of the same episode](http://www.gateworld.net/universe/s2/transcripts/213.shtml) yields no interesting results.

In order to save me from watching the episode again with a scrutinous ear, or reading the whole transcript, can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Or is the Wiki page simply making it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wiki is doubtless referring to this part:

> (An alarm begins to blare.)
>
> WRAY: What's happening?
>
> GREER: That's Incoming.

... but I think they're misinterpreting it. It's clear from the episode that "incoming" in this case refers to a *missile* (well, *ship*, in this case, but with a bomb as payload, so same difference), not a stargate wormhole. If it were a wormhole, it'd be a routine occurrence; instead, what we see is general alarm and scrambling to evacuate/seek cover:

> (People are running for the nearest exit. Camille starts to follow them but Greer grabs her arm and stops her.)
>
> GREER: No-no-no-no.
>
> WRAY: What are you doing?
>
> (He starts pulling her towards the door to the nearest office.)
>
> GREER: We have to go for cover.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Agreed on all points. Thanks. :)

Comment: I've added a response on the Wiki itself, reading: `He doesn't say that at all; he says "that's 'incoming'", referring to an audible alarm, and his reaction to this (as well as that of everybody else around) is that of panic and scrambling for cover. It seems clear that "incoming" in this context therefore meant incoming ordnance/attack, and not an incoming wormhole. There is no indication that the Stargate is not still homed at the SGC, a super-secure bunker miles below the surface where it makes inordinately more sense to place it than at the Pentagon.`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe Stargate Command was changed to Homeworld Command, because Earth now has many off-world posts.

Comment: No; Homeworld Command is based at the Pentagon, and has existed since the beginning of Season Eight (at which time it was known unofficially as "The Department Of Homeworld Security"). General Hammond was its first commander, his first post-SGC role. We have seen that the SGC continued to exist in its original function (more or less) for at least four years afterwards. Homeworld Command became the overarching body in charge of not only the SGC but also the relatively new non-Stargate projects such as the ever-expanding fleet of interstellar vessels.